Why expo-background-fetch is not fetching at all in IOS
I've problem my app never gets a chance to fetch the requests, i thought maybe IOS needs time to initialize that so i tried on three real devices and waited three days using build from Testflight, but never got it ... When it gets fetch chance it should fetch my backend to give like a fake request (i made this for me to confirm its working), but it never fetches it but when i try to do it manually Xcode > Debug > Simulate Background fetch  it works fine.
here's my App.tsx
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Provider, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { StateInterface, store } from "./mredux";
import Layout from "./parts/Layout";
import {
  NativeAppEventEmitter,
  NativeEventEmitter,
  NativeModules,
} from "react-native";
import { Auth0Provider, useAuth0 } from "react-native-auth0";
import AppleHealthKit, {
  HealthKitPermissions,
  HealthObserver,
} from "react-native-health";
import { getHealthData, permissionsHealth } from "./utils/permissions";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";
import * as BackgroundFetch from "expo-background-fetch";
import axios from "axios";
import { getItem } from "./utils/asyncstorage";
import * as Device from "expo-device";
import { updateMainState } from "./utils/updatestate";
import { pushHealthData, requestFetchProcess } from "./utils/api.service";

const BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK = "com.transistorsoft.health";

TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, async ({ error }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Background fetch error:", error);
    return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.Failed;
  }

  console.log("Background fetch task started at", new Date().toISOString());
  try {
    // THIS FAKE REQUEST I WAS TALKING ABOUT
    requestFetchProcess()
      .then(() => console.log("DONE!"))
      .catch(console.log);
    fetchHealthData()
      .then(() => console.log("DONE!"))
      .catch(console.log);
    console.log(
      "Background fetch task completed successfully at",
      new Date().toISOString()
    );
    return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.NewData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Background fetch task error:", error);
    return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.Failed;
  }
});

export const registerBackgroundFetchAsync = async () => {
  try {
    const status = await BackgroundFetch.getStatusAsync();
    console.log("Background fetch status:", status);
    console.log(
      "Background fetch status:",
      BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchStatus.Available
    );
    if (
      status === BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchStatus.Restricted ||
      status === BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchStatus.Denied
    ) {
      console.log("Background fetch is not enabled.");
      return;
    }

    await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, {
      minimumInterval: 15 * 60, // Fetch data every 15 mins
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      startOnBoot: true,
    });

    console.log("Background fetch task registered successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error registering background fetch task:", error);
  }
};

const fetchHealthData = async () => {
  try {
    const healthData = await getHealthData(new Date());
    const deviceInfo = store.getState().mainReducer.deviceInfo;

    const req = await pushHealthData(healthData, deviceInfo, true);

    console.log("Server response:", req);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error fetching health data:", error);
  }
};

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    updateMainState({
      deviceInfo: {
        deviceType: Device.deviceType as unknown as string,
        manufacturer: Device.manufacturer,
        modelName: Device.modelName,
        osName: Device.osName,
      },
    });
    registerBackgroundFetchAsync();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
          <Layout />
      </Provider>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

Also i already added task name into BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers  in info.plist here's my config:
n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.transistorsoft.fetch</string>
        <string>com.transistorsoft.health</string>
    </array>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>lexy Connect</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.9</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.lexyhealth.connect</string>
                <string>com.lexyhealth.connect</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>auth0</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.lexyhealth.connect.auth0</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>exp+lexy-connect</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your Face ID biometric data.</string>
    <key>NSHealthClinicalHealthRecordsShareUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Read and understand clinical health data.</string>
    <key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Read and understand health data.</string>
    <key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Share workout data with other apps.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your location</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your location</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your location</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
        <string>processing</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>SplashScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
    <string>Light</string>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>

package.json
    ...
    "expo": "^51.0.8",
    "expo-background-fetch": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-task-manager": "~11.8.1",
    ...

I hope i can find a solution for this, if you have another solution i can do instead of expo one it'll be grateful
thank you guys
I tried all other packages and like everything, and nothing!

The "Simulate Background Fetch" menu item is for the older background refresh API. There is a different process to debug BGAppRefresh
